# Requiring an async function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to get my head around async/await in NodeJS.

I have a function in a file as follows:

```
const getAccessToken = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const oauthOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: oauthUrl,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + oauthToken
      },
      form: {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials'
      }
    };

    request(oauthOptions)
      .then((err, httpResponse, body) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject('ERROR : ' + err);
        }
        return resolve(body.access_token);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        reject('getAccessToken ERROR : ' + e);
      });
  });
};

module.exports = getAccessToken;
```

This file is saved as `twitter.js` in a `lib` folder

In my `index.js` file I have the following:

```
const getAccessToken = require('./lib/twitter');

let accessToken;

try {
  accessToken = await getAccessToken();
} catch (e) {
  return console.log(e);
}

console.log(accessToken);
```

I get an error trying to run this code saying:

```
>   accessKey = await getAccessToken();
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>     at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
>     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
>     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
>     at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Can I not `await` the required function as it is marked `async` ?

Comment: what nodejs version?

Comment: 8.1.4 (running on Ubuntu)

Comment: the function `getAccessToken = async () =>` shouldnt be async, and the peice of code `accessKey = await getAccessToken();` should be inside an async function

Comment: if I add `console.log(getAccessToken);` below  `const getAccessToken = require('./lib/twitter').getAccessToken;` it outputs `[AsyncFunction: getAccessToken]` which would suggest it is?

Comment: Ok I think I get what you say now.  I'll do some investigation, but thanks for your help @Naeem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code is already correct. **Without changing anything** in `twitter.js` you have two options to use it:

1. Functions marked with `async` always return promises. Therefore you can simply do:

   ```
   const getAccessToken = require('./lib/twitter');

   getAccessToken().then(accessToken => {
       console.log(accessToken);
   })
   ```
2. All functions that return promises can be `awaited` upon but you cannot use await outside of an `async` marked functions. So you can also do:

   ```
   const getAccessToken = require('./lib/twitter');

   (async function () {
       var accessToken = await getAccessToken();
       console.log(accessToken);
   })();
   ```

The async/await keywords does not change how async functions behave. You **still** cannot wait on async functions synchronously, you can only do that inside an asynchronous function. Async/await is just a syntax sugar on top of promises.

Comment: I was facing the same problem. I had a async function and at my index file, it was exported like that:

module.exports = {
importedAsync: require('./myAsyncFunction')
}

and finally, I imported it again from index.js in some different place.

const { importedAsync } = require('./lib/index.js').

As result, I got:  " importedAsync is not a function".

In my case, it was solved by importing myFunction directly:
const myAsyncFunction = require('./lib/myAsyncFunction.js').

It worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track, however `await` can only be used *inside* an async function. So you have your structure backwards, and can be easily solved by changing a few things. However I suggest you overlook your code and make some structural changes. But here is a working version of your code:

```
const getAccessToken = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const oauthOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: oauthUrl,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + oauthToken
      },
      form: {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials'
      }
    };

    request(oauthOptions)
      .then((err, httpResponse, body) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject('ERROR : ' + err);
        }
        return resolve(body.access_token);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        reject('getAccessToken ERROR : ' + e);
      });
  });
};

module.exports = getAccessToken;
```

And then:

```
const getAccessToken = require('./lib/twitter');

(async function() {
  try {
    let accessToken = await getAccessToken();
    console.log(accessToken);
  } catch (e) {
    return console.log(e);
  }
})()
```

This is a simple fix to your code to illustrate that you've got it backwards, and some structural changes are in order.

Comment: No need to use a promise here. The `async` keyword is a promise generator.

Comment: Thank you @Svenskunganka thats got it working.  I appreciate your help

Comment: @Sven I have a similar use case. although I need to make my Token acessible to all  other functions in my code. How can I do that? in this case If I am not mistaken I can only call the other functions after the access token. If I declared another async function in this file that would require the accessToken I would have to call it again and again. As many times as functions that would require it. Any ideia?